# Gradle error with lack of mainClassName property in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I have graddle configuration with two subprojects and when I want do *build* the project the following error is thrown:

```
Executing external task 'build'...
:core:compileJava
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes
:core:jar
:core:startScripts FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':core:startScripts'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
```

My configuration:
ROOT - build.gradle:

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    group = 'pl.morecraft.dev.morepianer'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    run {
        main = project.getProperty('mainClassName')
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.getProperty('name'),
                    'Implementation-Version': project.getProperty('version'),
                    'Main-Class': project.getProperty('mainClassName')
        }
    }

}

task copyJars(type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from(subprojects.jar)
    into project.file('/jars')
}
```

ROOT - setting.gradle:

```
include 'app'
include 'core'
```

APP PROJECT - build.gradle:

`EMPTY`

CORE PROJECT - build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
}
```

AND BOTH SUBPROJECTS (SIMILAR) - gradle.properties:

```
version = 0.1-SNAPSHOT
name = MorePianer Core Lib
mainClassName = pl.morecraft.dev.morepianer.core.Core
```

I've tried to add the mainClassName property in many places, but it does not work. This is even stranger, that It worked a couple days ago as it is. I'm using gradle for first time and I'm thinking about switching back to maven.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `application` plugin needs to know the main class for when it bundles the application.

In your case, you apply the `application` plugin for each subproject without specifying the main class for each of those subprojects.

I had the same problem and fixed it by specifying "mainClassName" at the same level as `apply plugin: 'application'` :

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.something.MyMainClass'
```

If you want to specify it in the `gradle.properties` file you might have to write it as : `projectName.mainClassName = ..`

Comment: I've tried to add:
`apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'pl.morecraft.dev.morepianer.core.Core'`
or `projectName.mainClassName` in properties but unfortunately nothing helped :/

Comment: Have you tried putting the line mainClassName in the build file instead of the properties file ?

Comment: for Kotlin DSL, when specifying the `application` plugin in `plugins { application /* ... */ }`, also configure it with: `application { mainClassName = "com.something.MyMainClass" }`

Comment: I just deleted this line from `build.gradle` (I'm using IntelliJ) `mainClassName = 'MyProjectName'`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting up mainClassName try to create

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'com.something.MyMainClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Please look at [Gradle fails when executes run task for scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216287/gradle-fails-when-executes-run-task-for-scala)

Comment: Thank You! This did the trick with gradle version 4.4 and SpringBoot 1.4.0

Comment: This worked, except I could not use the name "run" so I used "customRun".
With "run":
"Cannot add task 'run' as task with that name already exists."

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we bind a gradle script with the **application** plugin, Gradle expects us to point out the starting point of the application. This is neccessary because, Gradle will start bundling your application (jar/zip) using the given location as the entry point.
This error is thrown simply because **Gradle** knows that you want to bundle your application but is clueless about where to start the bundling process.

Answer (score 0):

One can specify the `mainClassName` as a project extended property:

```
ext {
    mainClassName = 'com.something.MyMainClass'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue in my project and solved it by excluding from gradle.properties:

```
#ogr.gradle.configurationdemand = true
```

Comment: Incorrect suggestion. This is not at all related to the issue.