# Gradle fails when executes run task for scala

Tags: scala, gradle

I created a `HelloWorld` app and I was able to execute *build* task but fail to execute *run* task.
I got the following error:

> Could not find or load main class Demo

The following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies{
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.2"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'Demo'
}
```

My source code *Demo.scala*:

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Helo World")
   }
}
```

My file structure:

```
build
src\main\scala\Demo.scala
build.gradle
```

I am using gradle 3.0 and Java 1.8.0_91.
It looks to me that I am missing some settings related to *classpath*.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the `classpath` as well. Change `run` task declaration to:

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
   main = 'Demo'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And it will work fine. [Demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/39216287).

To print the classpath:

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'Demo'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    doFirst {
      classpath.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Any idea how to print classpath from gradle in this case. If i do _println(classpath)_ it prints  "file collection". In other words I am trying to do simple debugging.

Comment: @Mika16, to print the classpath see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It looks i  can skip doFirst {} and just put classpath.each { println it }

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Gradle application plugin, which will add the run task automatically. Then simply specify the main class:

```
mainClassName = "Demo"
```

You build.gradle would then look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'application'
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies{
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.2"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}


mainClassName = 'Demo'
```

Comment: It does not work. I got "could not set unknown property mainClassName" in this case.